# Visp library - how to resize image

Tags: c++, vision

I am using Visp computer vision library and now I have a problem. I want to resize my image and next display it in window. I use function resize but I get some broken image. Here is my code:

```
vpImageIo::read(I,"test.jpg");
vpDisplayGDI d(I);
vpDisplay::setTitle(I, "My image");

I.resize(10,10);
vpDisplay::display(I);
vpDisplay::flush(I);
```

Maybe someone had the same problem in the past and resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
I.resize(10,10);
```

will only change the dimension of the image.

To resize the image, you have to use [`vpImageTools::resize()`](http://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-daily/classvpImageTools.html#a3a50b695db9330cf6cabe586af9f0133). Be careful, the function cannot work in-place (the source and destination images must be different).

What you want should be something like this:

```
  vpImage<vpRGBa> I_src, I;
  vpImageIo::read(I_src, "test.jpg");
  vpImageTools::resize(I_src, I, I_src.getWidth()/2, I_src.getHeight()/2);

  vpDisplayGDI d(I);
  vpDisplay::setTitle(I, "My image");

  vpDisplay::display(I);
  vpDisplay::flush(I);
  vpDisplay::getClick(I);
```

Comment: Ok, thats work better. I mean I have not see the broken image in my window. But now I have all white image.

Comment: Try using absolute image path or try with another images. What is the image type in your code? Are you using `vpImage<vpRGBa>`?

Comment: Yes, I am using vpImage<vpRGBa>. When I display the original image it shows correct image so thats probably not the problem with image path.

Comment: Ok, I resolve the problem. I did not flush image after display it, even it was in my code above. So it was always show white background. When I add vpDisplay::flush(I) everything works fine.